# Is there a specific way to extract file paths from netCDF4 files?

Tags: python, data-science, netcdf, netcdf4

Whenever I extract file names from a netCDF4 file, the individual letters come out straddled by a 'b' and apostrophes. So the filepath "/home/data" looks like:
[b'/' b'h' b'o' b'm' b'e' b'/' b'd' b'a' b't' b'a']

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to convert this to a filepath that looks normal?

I am extracting the filepath with the following code:

```
filepath = '/Users/jchap/Desktop/img_tags.nc'
with nc4.Dataset(filepath,'r') as ncid:
    L1fileName = ncid.variables['L1fileName'][:]
print(L1fileName[0])
```

And then receive the following mishmash results in lieu of a filepath:

```
[b'/' b'h' b'o' b'm' b'e' b'/' b'd' b'a' b't' b'a' b'w' b'o' b'r' b'k'
 b'-' b'c' b'e' b'r' b's' b'a' b't' b'-' b'p' b'u' b'b' b'l' b'i' b'c'
 b'/' b'c' b'a' b'c' b'h' b'e' b'/' b'p' b'r' b'o' b'j' b'e' b'c' b't'
 b'/' b's' b'1' b'a' b'-' b'w' b'v' b'1' b'-' b's' b'l' b'c' b'-' b'v' 
 b'v' b'-' b'2' b'0' b'0' b'2' b'f' b'0' b'9' b'b' b'-' b'0' b'1' b'3' 
 b'.' b't' b'i' b'f' b'f']
```

Note that the data "class" is: <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried your code on several .nc files of mine, I always came out with masked arrays filled with `[------.....------]`. 

What is the goal of your efforts, or what file path do you want to extract?

Comment: @CrynetOmega Thanks for taking a look! Yeah I keep getting masked arrays. I have a netcdf file with image 'labels' that are associated with specific image file names. I need to make arrays of both the labels and the filenames so that I can match each label to its own image.

Comment: @CrynetOmega I want to extract all of the file paths in the file but the way I am currently doing it has each character is straddled with: b' '

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [b'/' b'h' b'o' b'm' b'e' b'/' b'd' b'a' b't' b'a' b'w' b'o' b'r' b'k'
 b'-' b'c' b'e' b'r' b's' b'a' b't' b'-' b'p' b'u' b'b' b'l' b'i' b'c'
 b'/' b'c' b'a' b'c' b'h' b'e' b'/' b'p' b'r' b'o' b'j' b'e' b'c' b't'
 b'/' b's' b'1' b'a' b'-' b'w' b'v' b'1' b'-' b's' b'l' b'c' b'-' b'v' 
 b'v' b'-' b'2' b'0' b'0' b'2' b'f' b'0' b'9' b'b' b'-' b'0' b'1' b'3' 
 b'.' b't' b'i' b'f' b'f']

s = s.replace("b\'", '').replace("[","").replace("']","")
print(s)
[out]: '/home/datawork-cersat-public/cache/project/s1a-wv1-slc-vv-2002f09b-013.tiff'
```

The reason for this is briefly explained here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal-in-Python

Comment: Hmm when I use this type of approach it deletes all of the "b" values that are in my file path, not just the ones followed by a slash, making the file path unusable. Do you know any other way to go about it?

Comment: nevermind, I made a few more edits and I think I got it working well with this method. Thanks!